# Regex to keep null input

Tags: java, arrays, regex, split, null

I a currently working on a program that splits a full sentence string into an array of string by words, whitespace, and punctuation. However I also want to be able to make the program do something if the sentence that was inputed is null. Currently my regular expression that I have is throwing out any null input. The expression is:

```
String[] fragments = sentence.split("(?<=\\b|[^\\p{L}])");
```

Is there a way to modify this regular expression so that if it comes across a null input, the array will contain that null value so it can be processed later in the program?

Comment: Null as in `null` or as in `""` ?

Comment: I have to account for both. So it has to be null.

Comment: What is your expected output in these cases? `null` you would have to catch beforehand or sentence.split will throw NPE.

Comment: `""` is not null -- it's a non-null, empty string. It's good to get out of the habit of calling it null, because the two things work pretty differently, and conflating them can lead to confusion.

Comment: If the value passed in is null I am just trying to get the value returned to also be null without throwing an exception, however, I'm not sure that is possible.

Comment: Anyway, the solution is to just write and if-else. If the string is null, set fragments to null. Though an empty array would be better than null there.

Comment: `String[] fragments = (sentence == null) ? null : sentence.split("(?<=\\b|[^\\p{L}])");`

Comment: @yshavit, if he's following Oracle semantics, then his program may very well treat `(null)` and `""` as the same thing, just like Oracle DBMS does.

Comment: @yshavit "Though an empty array would be better than null there." - How do you know? Maybe it is a difference if it is null or empty?

Comment: I got it to work with that. Thanks!

Comment: @M.Prokhorov It's still confusing to use the word for both when talking "in Java".

Comment: @Fidor In nearly all cases, an empty array is the way to go. So you're right, I should have added "almost definitely" between "would" and "be." But given that `split` will never return an empty array (if there are no splits matched, it still returns a single-element array), it's unlikely that there's a good reason to differentiate between "null" and "empty." Empty arrays have benefits like not having to treat them specially when you want to loop over their elements, or not loop if empty. This isn't just my opinion, it's that of many experienced Java programmers (e.g. Effective Java #43).

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] fragments = (sentence == null) ? null : sentence.split("(?<=\\b|[^\\p{L}])");
```

Given your requirement, this should

- return `null` if input is null.
- return an array with a single entry of "" if input is "".
- return the array as expected if not "" nor `null`.